# Sum of two random numbers with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a program with Javascript that prints two random numbers and calculates their sum. It should be really easy, but for some reason I can't get the program to work. I've got the program to print random numbers, but I can't get it to add the numbers together. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>

        <p id="myBtn"></p>
        <p id="number1"></p>
        <p id="number2"></p>

        <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Get random number</button>


        <script>

            var allNumbers = 0;

            function myFunction() {
                num1 = document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                num2 = document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                var inTotal = num1 + num2;
                var allNumbers =+ inTotal;
            }

            document.write(allNumbers);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct! Here's a few tips on how to fix it:

- You have two elements with the same `id` attribute: the `<p>` and the `<button>` element. In HTML, `id` attributes should be unique on a page, so you should change one of the `id` attributes to something else. For example, you could change the `id` of the `<button>` element to "myBtn".
- When you click the button, the `myFunction()` function is called and the random numbers are generated and displayed in the `<p>` elements, but the sum of the numbers is not displayed anywhere. To fix this, you can add another `<p>` element where the sum of the numbers will be displayed.
- In the `myFunction()` function, the `inTotal` variable is local to the function, so it is not available outside the function. To fix this, you can add a global variable called `total` that will hold the sum of the numbers, and then update the `total` variable inside the `myFunction()` function.
- Finally, you are using the `document.write()` method to display the sum of the numbers, but this method will overwrite the entire page with the output. Instead, you can use the `innerHTML` property of the `<p>` element to update the element's contents with the sum of the numbers.

Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>

        <p id="number1"></p>
        <p id="number2"></p>
        <p id="total"></p>

        <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Get random number</button>

        <script>
            var total = 0;

            function myFunction() {
                num1 = document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                num2 = document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                total = num1 + num2;
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Now the program works as it should. I thought that the id of the button must be created separately inside the <p> element, because of that the same id appeared twice in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>

        <p id="myBtn"></p>
        <p id="number1"></p>
        <p id="number2"></p>
        
        <p id="getRandom"></p>

        <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Get random number</button>


        <script>

            
            function myFunction() {
                var allNumbers = 0;
            
                num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                
                document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = num1
                document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = num2
                var inTotal = num1 + num2;
                allNumbers += inTotal;
                
                document.getElementById("getRandom").innerHTML = `SUM : ${allNumbers}`;
                //document.write(allNumbers);
            }

            

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did all the calculation inside the scope function but tried displaying from the outside without returning any value. Either you have to return the value or you have to use `document.write(...)` inside the function, somewhat like this

```
var allNumbers = 0;

            function myFunction() {
                num1 = document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                num2 = document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1);
                var inTotal = num1 + num2;
                var allNumbers =+ inTotal;
                document.write(allNumbers);
            }
```

That would erase everything on the document and only the value of the allNumbers variable will be displayed. I'm assuming you want to display result on the different element id. So, Instead of `document.write(allNumbers)`, I advise you create another p tag as `<p id = "answer"></p>` and use `document.getElementById("answer").innerText = allNumbers`. This will display the answer along with num1 and num2.